# Image preview missing in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-frontend

Does Chrome Developer tools stopped displaying preview of CSS background images? It used to display it like this:

[image]

But now it's not showing the preview image.

sometimes I just want have a look at the background-image to see how the UI effect being implemented(e.g. [effect](https://jianliao.com/site)).Anyone knows how to bring it back **without modifying of the chrome version**? If not, please show me the official declaration for this.

Checked on Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113